# Op-amp produces uneven output

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]I connect op-amp supply with -12V and +12V, expecting to toggle output in such way. But I get ~-11V or +12V. Why aren't they even (-12 and 12V)? Why negative side is smaller?
I tried [LM2904P](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2904v.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1690619719953&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Flm2904v) and [LF353P](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf353.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1690619757668&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.lt%252F) - they both reduce negative output.

On input there is 2.5V and 5V (or GND) for toggling.

Comment: 1. Have you looked at the datasheets you linked? 2. output swing will depend on the loading as well as supply voltages. If you are loading the output with a resistor to +12V it will yield different results than if the resistor is to GND or -12V. You have not described what you are doing- a schematic is usually better than words.

Comment: Provide your schematic.

Comment: There are no load on output - just voltmeter. I edited the question and added schematic. In LTSpice everything works nicely. Of course the opamp here is perfect.

Comment: Use rail to rail output Op Amp.

Comment: Use the correct op-amp model in LTspice and you’ll usually get a better approximation of real behavior. Also, read the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want rail-to-rail output, you need to use an opamp that is specified to have rail-to-rail output (sometimes abbreviated as RRO).

The output ranges are given in the data sheet.  Even if an opamp does have rail-to-rail output, it often does so using extra circuitry, so when exploiting rail-to-rail capability, you may get more points of crossover distortion than just on polarity change.

It is also frequent to have opamps that are specified to include the negative supply rail on output and/or input but not the positive rail: that can be useful for circuitry with just a single positive supply voltage.

When you are actually doing comparisons, you might want to use a comparator instead of an opamp.  Those can provide cleaner output since they do not need to bother about stability with negative feedback, and they don't have differential input protection diodes (many opamps do) that limit the input difference voltage and cause headaches in comparison applications.

Answer (score 0):

> *I connect op-amp supply with -12V and +12V, expecting to toggle output
> in such way.*

You need to use a dedicated comparator. Sure, an op-amp can behave like a poor man's comparator but, when you use an op-amp as a comparator, you need to read the data sheet and recognize that many op-amps cannot drive the output fully to either rail and, many of them are asymmetrical in this respect.

Even so-called rail-to-rail op-amps (and even dedicated comparators) might only get the output to within 5 mV of the power rails on a very light output load current.

Comment: Could you tell me how would I use comparator? Would this work: https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/SGST/SGSTS36256/SGSTS36256-1.pdf?hkey=52A5661711E402568146F3353EA87419 I see it only has two inputs, so I dont thing it would be enough?